# Using Types as Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am using AutoMapper dll.
Trying to write a method for mapping process.

```
    public ServiceResult<LoginModel> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
            //-----from here
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<LoginModel, User>();
            });

            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var user = new User();

            var dest = mapper.Map<LoginModel, User>(model);
            //------ to here

            return new ServiceResult<LoginModel>(model);
    }
```

So I need to get LoginModel, User, and model as dynamic.
The method should look like below simply (only for example, I could not find a way to do this),

```
 public object Map(Type source, Type destination, object model)
{
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<source, destination>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var user = new User(); (Model of [destination])

        var dest = mapper.Map<source, destination>(model);
        //map data from model to dest

        return new ServiceResult<LoginModel>(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Map method to generic one:

```
public object Map<TSource, TDestination>(object model)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
            });

            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var user = new User();

            var dest = mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(model);
            //map data from model to dest

            return new ServiceResult<LoginModel>(model);
        }
```

Comment: No, it isn't. AM is mainly a cache and that cache lives in MapperConfiguration. You app should have only one such object. So unless you're willing to spend some time understanding how AM works, you're better off mapping by hand.